# Garbage characters returned when using literals with DB2 SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, db2

Statement is similar to this -

```
$sql = "SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, fooDate1, fooDate2, 'Open' FROM some.table";
```

And I get back in HTML this

```
1   801566  11451   06/21/2011  06/22/2011  ����
```

I assume this has something to do with character encoding?

Edit:

I found the solution on Zend forums.

"2. Add the following line to Apache configuration file /www/zendsvr/con/httpd.conf : 
DefaultFsCCSID 37"

Source:
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=8154&p=28348&hilit=db2+ascii#p28348

Comment: Try "SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, fooDate1, fooDate2, 'Open' FROM some.'table'"; Not sure but table may be reserved.

Comment: @Headspin:That is not the problem, since the query is returning a result set. It's a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3, fooDate1, fooDate2, \"Open\" FROM some.table";
```

Comment: Got this error with that:
42703: Column or global variable Open not found. SQLCODE=-206

Comment: DB2 uses single quotes for string literals. Double quotes would make it treat it like a column name.